# Log laws proof using only rational exponents

Tags: logarithms, rational-numbers

For all **real** $a>0$ and **rational** $b>0$,

Show that $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$

Comment: How exactly do you define $\ln$? Are you aware $e^{\ln (x)}=x,\forall x>0$?

Comment: @user236182  Personally, I know what $\ln$ is but for the purpose of this proof I want to define it as the area between $1$ and $x_0$ under the curve $\frac1x$ where $x>0$

Comment: @Yeah.. Then __STATE__ that in your question so that users can answer your question properly, not everyone even reads the comments when they answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$b\ln a=b\int_1^a\frac{1}{x}dx=\int_1^a\frac{b}{x}dx$

Let $u=x^b$

Then $du= bx^{b-1}dx$ and $\frac{du}{u}=\frac{b}{x}dx$

Therefore, $\int_1^a\frac{b}{x}dx = \int_1^{a^b}\frac{du}{u}=\ln {a^b}$

Answer (score 0):

$$x = \log_b(a^n)$$
$$b^x=a^n$$
$$(b^x)^{1/n}=(a^n)^{1/n}$$
$$b^{x/n}=a$$
$$x/n = \log_b(a)$$
$$x = n \log_b(a)$$
$$\log_b(a^n) = n\log_b(a)$$

Comment: See the comments for OP's definition of $\ln$.

Comment: @user236182 ah dang... there goes all my beautiful work proving this just using exponent laws. Oh well :P

Comment: I still think it's much easier to just notice $\ln\left(a^b\right)=b\ln(a)\iff e^{\ln\left(a^b\right)}=e^{b\ln(a)}$ and $e^{b\ln (a)}=\left(e^{\ln(a)}\right)^b$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already proved the main property
$$
\ln(xy)=\ln x+\ln y
$$
(for positive reals $x$ and $y$). By an easy induction you get that
$$
\ln(a^m)=m\ln a
$$
for a positive integer $m$. If $m<0$, you have
$$
\ln(a^m)=\ln\frac{1}{a^{-m}}=-\ln(a^{-m})=-(-m\ln a)=m\ln a
$$

Now suppose $b=m/n$, where, without loss of generality, $n>0$. Then
$$
\ln(a^b)=\ln((a^{1/n})^m)=m\ln(a^{1/n})
$$
by the above argument, so we're left to prove that
$$
\ln(a^{1/n})=\frac{1}{n}\ln a
$$
Since
$$
n\left(\frac{1}{n}\ln a\right)=\ln a
$$
and
$$
n\ln(a^{1/n})=\ln((a^{1/n})^n)=\ln a
$$
we get the desired result.

Comment: the OP wants a solution in terms of integrals I believe

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I don't think so.

Comment: @Brevan You're right, but the OP should have stated that in the question, on viewing the question I have also answered not using integrals.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln(x)=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt \\ \text{ so } \ln(x^r)=\int_1^{x^r} \frac{1}{t} dt \\ \text{ and then differentiating both sides gives} \\ [\ln(x^r)]'=(x^r)' \cdot \frac{1}{x^r}=\frac{r}{x} \\ \text{ now integrating both sides ... see if you can finish from here } \ln(x^r)=... \\ $

Comment: I see John's answer now. He went in the opposite direction of me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming knowledge of

$(a^m)^n=a^{mn}\tag{1}$

Now let $a^m=b$ and $a^n = c$

Then from $(1)$

we have $b^n=(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$

so $\log_a(b^n)=mn$

therefore $n\log_a b=\log_a(b^n)$

Hence

$\color{blue}{\fbox{$\log_a (b^n) = n\log_a b$}}$

I did this for general logarithms, as I think it's good practice to generalize proofs, but the above proof works exactly the same for natural logarithms (which you were asking about) also.

Comment: OP wants a proof with integrals; see the comments.

Comment: @user236182 Thanks for pointing that out, I spotted that after I posted. But since the others have already posted good answers via integration I shall leave this as it is as I was simply answering the original question that was posted by the OP and it says nothing about using integrals in the question as you can see.